# Softmax inverse for distance measure

Tags: optimization

I have a distance measure going from 0 to infitiny, where 0 indicates closeness.

I need to perform a transformation in order that the distances **sum up to 1**. Therefore, **softmax** seems appropriate, especially that the gap between the values is not constant but increase with the distance, so 1 to 2 is much closer than 9 to 10.

My issue is that I want the opposite to a softmax transformation.

Imagine the following vector  `x = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 10)`

If I apply a softmax transformation (using `R`)

```
softmax = round( exp(x) / sum(exp(x)), 2)
```

I get

```
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.01 0.99
```

But I want the opposite of that, I want the 0 being closest to 1 and so on.

How could I do that?

Comment: Replace $\exp(x)$ with $\exp(-x)$ in your formula. This yields $${\tt 0.26\;0.26\;0.26\;0.09\; 0.09\;0.03\;0.00\;0.00\;0.00}$$

Comment: I just thought about this, thanks make sense